# how to make a page similar as youtube page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to design a page to be similar as YouTube home page but with one difference (i am using a swipe to show next results in YouTube on-click on the arrows data videos are changed ). my problem is on resize i want to do the same as on YouTube page and hide results relatively with the screen size .

## HTML :

```
     <div class="borderbotom">
        <a href="#"class="resto">Restaurants</a>
        <div class="swiper-container marginfromborder">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">

                <div class="swiper-slide">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 nopad">
                         <div class="greydivresto">
                            <img class="fwimgslider" alt="" src="../images/resto1.png">
                            <p class="firsttext">The Northern Lights: Trip of a Lifetime</p>
                            <p class="sndtext">Where to go to see the Northern Lights, including information on Iceland,...</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 nopad">
                         <div class="greydivresto">
                            <img class="fwimgslider" alt="" src="../images/resto1.png">
                            <p class="firsttext">The Northern Lights: Trip of a Lifetime</p>
                            <p class="sndtext">Where to go to see the Northern Lights, including information on Iceland,...</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 nopad">
                         <div class="greydivresto">
                            <img class="fwimgslider" alt="" src="../images/resto1.png">
                            <p class="firsttext">The Northern Lights: Trip of a Lifetime</p>
                            <p class="sndtext">Where to go to see the Northern Lights, including information on Iceland,...</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 nopad">
                         <div class="greydivresto">
                            <img class="fwimgslider" alt="" src="../images/resto1.png">
                            <p class="firsttext">The Northern Lights: Trip of a Lifetime</p>
                            <p class="sndtext">Where to go to see the Northern Lights, including information on Iceland,...</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>   
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

## JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
   var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
     nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
     prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
     slidesPerView: 'auto', 
     centeredSlides: false,
     spaceBetween: 10
 });
});
```

the swiper is working fine but anyone has an an idea how display less of result on resize depending on the screen size?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is CSS Media Queries.
This allows you to declare different styles for different screen widths.
You'll be able to make something like :

> "If my page width is less than XXX, the player should be placed HERE
>   and take the width XXX"

For example :

```
@media (max-width:1024px){
    #player{
        width: 100%;
    }

    #sidebar{
        display: none;
    }
}
```